# Payoneer API to send money automatically

Tags: php, api

I really need help from you guys. Does anyone know of any method which allows Scheduled payments from Payoneer Card to other Payoneer Cards? Or is there any Payoneer API for PHP that can do that?

Just like MassPay Service of Paypal.

Please, help!

Regards!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an API, there might be an [SDK](http://community.payoneer.com/topic/131-payoneer-sdk/).

Comment: @NickFury -- Can you please guide me to the SDK page?

Comment: Here's what I've found in the matter. Hope this helps get you started: https://partners.payoneer.com/WebApps/Admin/Files/APIGuide.pdf.

Comment: That link is dead @dandrews.

Comment: I found this https://developer.payoneer.com/docs/MassPayout/APIDoc/apis